# accessing variables in the debugging session with ipython and %pdb on

Tags: python, ipython

I'm new to ipython and I am trying to use ipython to debug my code. I did:

```
[1]: %pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON
```

and then

```
In [2]: %run mycode.py
```

and in the code, I have 1/0 so it raises an exception and will automatically goes into the debug session.

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division

ipdb> variable
array([ 0.00704313, -1.34700666, -2.81474391])
```

So I can access variables. But when I do the following:

```
ipdb> b = variable
*** The specified object '= variable' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.
```

But this works:

```
ipdb> b = self.X
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`b` is used to set break points. So whatever follows `b` is expected to be a function or line number.

If you type `ipdb> help` you will see the full list of commands (reserved words).

You could use, say, `x` or `y` as a variable:

```
ipdb> y = variable
```

or

```
ipdb> exec 'b = variable'
```

Comment: Is there any way to overload this b command? In my application variable name b occurs a lot naturally, and it is a pain not being able to use it.

Comment: @joon: Having one-letter variable names is generally speaking not a good programming practice. Maybe this is problem should motivate you to change the variable name. I realize that may be hard to do. In that case you might try `exec 'b = variable'`.

Comment: Of course. It is just the character b is natural choice for the mathematical counterpart. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use '!' ([pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)):
! statement
Execute the (one-line) statement in the context of the current stack frame. The exclamation point can be omitted *unless the first word of the statement resembles a debugger command*. To set a global variable, you can prefix the assignment command with a global statement on the same line, e.g.:

```
global list_options; list_options = ['-l']
```

Answer (score 3):

In python3 you can use a single exclamation mark to override ipdb commands

`!b`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
locals()["b"] = variable
```